# Undetected Chromedriver not using most recent chromedriver for my browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am having some issue getting my `undetected_chromedriver` to be on version `Chromium: 116.0.5845.96`. This issue just started today I have tried nearly everything I can think of, from reinstalling the module, to reinstalling the browsers, and even tested with the `version_main=116` paramater which should have fixed it, but it seems that `version_main` only goes to `114`.

**Here's my code.**

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
```

This is being launched on Chrome Version : `Version 116.0.5845.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, returns this error in the console. `from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97`

Answer (score 6):

There's an open ticket on it here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1477

---

Until the fix is available, you can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode as an alternative, which has a slightly modified version of `undetected-chromedriver`.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

---

SeleniumBase also has other formats with its own API:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.sleep(3)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1"):
        sb.get_new_driver(undetectable=True)
        sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
        sb.sleep(3)
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=3)
```

Comment: Worked fine for me on windows, but I can't seem to get seleniumbase working on linux with google-chrome 116. Getting error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222` using Python 3.7

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
pip uninstall undetected_chromedriver
pip install undetected_chromedriver
```